# What's the point of switching Monica's and Rachel's rooms?

Tags: friends

In *Friends* Season 3 Episode 22 there's the following scene:

> *[Scene: Monica and Rachel's, Monica and Rachel are returning. Phoebe is still on hold.]*
>
> **Monica:** Hey!
> **Rachel:** Hey!
> **Phoebe:** Oh, is the play over?
> **Monica:** Yeah. Where were you?
> **Hold Voice:** Thank you for your patience, you’re the next caller.
> **Monica:** You were the next caller five hours ago. You must be going crazy.
> **Phoebe:** Nah. I kept myself busy.
>
> *(Both Rachel and Monica walk into their bedrooms, stop, and come back into the living room with confused looks on their faces.)*
>
> **Phoebe:** Oh, okay, yeah. (to Monica) I put your stuff in her room, and her stuff in your room.
>
> *(They both look at each other, nod their heads ‘All right’ and follow their stuff into their new rooms.)*

Phoebe was near the phone on hold near to the phone all the time, how? And what is the point of doing something so bizarre like changing the stuff of people into other rooms?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. **She had them on speakerphone** (this is [shown](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLBR6x1r-ao) during the episode). So she would have heard it from the other room if they finally answered. I do that all the time with those customer services. :)
2. **She was bored**. So she did something as futile as switching the girls' bedrooms (BTW, this is also a [common prank](http://blog.muenchensfurniture.com/10-at-home-pranks-for-april-fools-day)). She was also making string figures at some point, because she was literally trapped in that house and going insane. (And lastly, remember that Phoebe is eccentric.)

Comment: Why didn't Monica get nuts then? We know that Monica will destroy the world -metaphorically- if a pencil got out of its place!

Comment: Well, that's a different question...  ;) I guess you're right, but I think that side of Monica was only taken to the extreme in later seasons. I think she's unlikely to fly off the handle over something like this in season 3, and she probably felt sorry for Phoebe anyway and let it slide.

Comment: Actually she was that anal about it since the beginning, I remember an episode where she couldn't sleep because she was worrying about a shoe in her hall! and it is not later than season 3 for sure coz I never got past that point.

Comment: Yeah, I think that was actually one of the show's first episodes. Still, they [Flanderized](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Flanderization) her to a great extent from like season 5 onwards.

Comment: Yes! and that left me in surprise of her passive reaction, I thought she will beat the hell out of her...

Comment: @ARGMAN - Presumably Phoebe simply did a good job. That would be enough to assuage Monica.

Comment: I don't agree, Richard. I think Monica is too anal to accept -even a good job- rearrangements OR to be assuaged!